# LibGdx Bluetooth Game with Android

Tags: libgdx, multiplayer, bluetooth

I've created a simple 2d platformer with libGdx and box2d and i wanted to add some kind of a multiplayer to it.I found an implementation over the internet that uses bluetooth with libGdx and i've tried to adapt it to my game but whenever i start the app it gives me this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 15414
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle com.badlogic.gdx.Files.internal(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:211)
                      at com.mygdx.game.screens.PlayScreen.<init>(PlayScreen.java:60)
                      at com.mygdx.game.views.fragment.GdxFragment.onCreateView(GdxFragment.java:31)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1264)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1366)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2409)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:77)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Application terminated.
```

This is the main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
    android:name="com.mygdx.game.views.fragment.GdxFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_libgdx"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


<fragment
    android:name="com.mygdx.game.views.fragment.BluetoothFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_ui"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"/>
```

I've also tried to build, rebuild the project but it's still giving me the same exception.
Do you guys know where the problem comes from? i don't really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your **libGDX** `AndroidApplication` isn't initialized. Make sure to call `initialize` in `onCreate` in your `AndroidLauncher` class.